# I can't print my array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I tried to print my array using to `Arrays.toString(array));` but still it gave me errors... And also ELEMENT IS FOUND is false statement but it mixes with the true statement when i tried to search an element in my array, 
for example.....

> I searched 4 in my array: 4 , 2, 3 ,5

but ELEMENT IS FOUND is still showing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class linee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int String;
        int value;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the Number of Element: ");
        String n = in.nextLine();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(n);
        String array[] = new String[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input the Number at array index " + i + ": ");
            array[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        Linear(array);
        System.out.print("\nDo you want to continue? YES = 1, NO = 2: ");
        value = in.nextInt();
        if (value == 1) {
            main(args);
        } else if (value == 2) {
            System.out.println("\nThank you for using the program.");
        }
    }

    public static void Linear(String[] array) {
        boolean flag = false;
        String key = "";
        int index = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number that you want to search: ");
        key = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(key)) {
                flag = true;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true) {
            System.out.println("Elements: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println("ELEMENT IS FOUND AT INDEX " + index);
        } else {
            System.out.println("ELEMENT IS NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you import java.util.Arrays?

Comment: "but still it gave me errors..." As these errors seem to be a secret, the answers are a secret as well.

Comment: This runs fine for me. Could you elaborate on the errors/problems please?

Comment: @anaxin 
linee.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
                                                System.out.println("Elements: " + Arrays.toString(array));
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class linee
1 error

Comment: I already made it work. thanks to @Paulo

Comment: According to your error message, you forgot to import java.util.Arrays as @Eran assumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `Object.toString(Object[] a)` spec:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are
>   converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from
>   Object, which describes their **identities** rather than their contents.

That is, you may want to print your elements in another way. An option is:

```
System.out.println("Elements: ");
for(String str: array) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```